# Ubikload pack jmeter test fails

Tags: gwt, jmeter, ubikloadpack

When running my recording i get the following error:
Error converting XML to GWTRPC format, message:class java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:3, see logs for more

Logs:

```
2016/05/25 09:28:12 ERROR - com.ubikingenierie.jmeter.plugin.gwt.preprocessor.GwtPreProcessor: Error converting XML to GWTRPC format, message:class java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:3, see logs for more details, query:

<GwtRequest>
<className>com.stibo.portal.framework.client.rpc.LoginService</className>
<parameters>
<string>username</string>
<string>password</string>
<null/>
<string>http://testsystem.com/</string>
</parameters>
  <returnType>com.stibo.portal.framework.client.security.UserCredentials</returnType>
<method>doLogin</method>
<serializationPolicy>175634C48105165283A8CE76F1923989</serializationPolicy>
<gwtVersion>7</gwtVersion>
<moduleBaseUrl>http://testsystem.com/test</moduleBaseUrl>
</GwtRequest> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at     com.ubikingenierie.jmeter.plugin.gwt.request.GwtRequestToXmlTransformerXStream.a(GwtRequestToXmlTransformerXStream.java:356)
at com.ubikingenierie.jmeter.plugin.gwt.request.GwtRequestToXmlTransformerXStream.a(GwtRequestToXmlTransformerXStream.java:233)
at com.ubikingenierie.jmeter.plugin.gwt.preprocessor.GwtPreProcessor.process(GwtPreProcessor.java:82)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:762)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:419)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your support ticket, this is a bug we fixed in version 4.2.2

Comment: Thanks for the quick support :)